# Comparing MD5 strings

Tags: java, string, md5

I have a java code where I am sending an md5 has over the socket to receive on the other side. I take in a password as the input and create its own md5 to check with the md5 recieved over the socket to authenticate.

Both the md5 strings have the same byte pattern, but the String.equals() returns a false when I do an equality test on both the md5 patterns. How can this be possible ?. Please help if anyone has an idea of what might be wrong ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Both the md5 strings have the same byte pattern"? How do you determine this?

Comment: Are you truly using `String.equals()`, and not, for example, calling `char[].equals()` ?

Comment: I did a new String(md5 byte array). And then comparing both the strings using String.equals(). By "both md5 have the same byte pattern" I mean, when I did a string.getBytes() on both the md5 strings, I see the same byte values in eclipse.

Comment: Here is the link to the code: http://pastebin.com/BtfvMhSi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MD5 is a `byte[]`. It's representation is *usually* a hex-string. The things to look at:

- the way you construct the hex string should be the same
- make sure you are not using `new String(bytes)`. This uses the default encoding, which varies across machines, and the encoding might not support some byte values.
- the letters should have the same case (lower/upper)

But you shouldn't compare the representation. You should compare the bytes: `Arrays.equals(ar1, ar2)`

Comment: Will give it a try and see if it works, should work hopefully. Thanks :)

Comment: This seems to be the solution, but can you explain why cant I do a string compare on a hex string and should always compare bytes ?

Comment: the hex string is simply a representation of the array. And if it is generated by slightly-differing algorithms, the output for the same byte arrays may differ

Comment: Oh okay. But I used the same algorithm, the default MD5 available in java SDK can that bring in differences too ?

Comment: the default md5 gives you bytes. How do you get strings?

Comment: I did a new String(md5 byte[]). Is that considered bad ?

Comment: yes, it's bad. It's not producing hex. It's producing something depending on the default encoding. Which may be changing. Or may be unable to map some bytes.

Comment: Aah yes, that seems like the core cause of the error. I converted the byte[] to hex in the wrong way..nice to know..thanks a lot Bozho!